# Установка Linux

Tags: windows

Как установить Linux как виртуальный раздел в Windows?

Comment: Линукс — это не раздел, это операционная система. Операционная система не может быть разделом.

Comment: Звучит примерно так: "Как тапки курица огурец?" Сформулируйте вопрос более понятно. Я исходя из Вашего вопроса могу только предположить, что Вам нужно установить Linux на виртуальную машину, чего я бы категорически не советовал, исходя из собственного опыта.

Comment: А что было в вашем опыте такого, что линукс на вирт. машине, дал негативные впечатления?

Comment: Предлагаю автору не пытаться умничать и не использовать слова, значения которых он пока не понимает и сформулировать хотелку так, как она есть в голове, а мы попытаемся предложить оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Я понял о чем он спрашивал. Это инсталлятор WIBU.Не на всех дистрибутивах он есть. На Mint-9 есть, а на 10 уже нет.Грузишься в Windows, когда он загрузится, берешь диск с дистрибутивом Linux, в дисковод его, открываешь диск, там ищешь знакомый "exe", запускаешь его -- это инсталлятор под Windows. Отвечаешь правильно на все вопросы, там сам увидишь. Но учти, диск "С" на который он (Linux) установится, в Linux не отображается. То есть, допустим есть 2 логических диска - "С" и "D", в "С" установился Linux (в виде приложения Windows), тогда всё, что на "D" будет доступно, а на "С" - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь виртуальную машину, делаешь к ней диск, вставляешь в реальные привод болванку, подключаешь к виртуальной машине привод с болванкой и ставишь linux.

Там все по пунктам будет написано, все конечно зависит от того какую систему ставишь.

Answer (score 0):

Может вопрос в том, что-бы "видеть" Linux раздел из Windows? Если ext3 - то Ext2IFS в помощь. ReiserFS  тоже можно примонтировать как раздел, но read-only (имеются Windows утилиты). С другими файловыми системами всё "плачевно"...